# C++ ошибка heap corruption detected after normal block c++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: хотел очистить член класса, представляющий
из себя динамический массив. delete[]str выдал ошибку с дебажной кучей. Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Где-то портите память. Или второй раз вызываете delete. Или вызываете delete с неверным указателем.

Без кода ничего более конкретного не скажу.

Comment: я проверял отладкой до вызова delete[]str содержит нормальный указатель

Comment: @dimasmephi, Вы серьезно верите в телепатию?

Comment: symbols &symbols::operator=(const symbols&ob)
 {
  char *k;
  if (this!=&ob)
  {
   delete[]str;
   str=NULL;
   if ((power=ob.power)!=0)
   {
    str=new char[this->power];
    strcpy(str,ob.str);
   }
  }
 return *this;
 }

Comment: Складывается впечатление, что Вы издеваетесь.

--

1. Выложите достаточно кода (вместе с описанием класса), вызывающим кодом, тестовыми данными и т.п.

2. Отформатируйте по человечески.


3. Проверьте, что во всех вызовах `strlen(ob.str) < power` (при равенстве завершающий ob.str nil не помещается).